# Can you extend differentiability in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of real and imaginary parts of a function to say the function is entire in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, entire-functions

Given a function $u(x,y)$ that is harmonic on $\mathbb{R}^2$ we know that there must exist a unique (up to constant additive) harmonic conjugate of u(x,y), called $v(x,y)$ that is also harmonic on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Therefore there will exist a function $f(z)=u(x,y)+i v(x,y)$ that is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

From here I want to claim that $f(z)$ is also entire on $\mathbb{C}$. This makes sense to me intuitively but I am having a bit of trouble formalizing the concept.

Comment: When you say "differentiable on $\Bbb R^2$" you mean "complex-differentiable on $\Bbb C$"? When you start with a $C^1$ function $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$, you must mention that it satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations to bridge the gap to $\Bbb C$, right?

Comment: I believe you are right. I was wondering how to formally show the work with the Cauchy Riemann equations.

Comment: The point is that the construction of the harmonic conjugate forces the Cauchy-Riemann equations to hold automatically.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Because $f$ is a holomorphic from $\mathbb C$ into $\mathbb C$, and therefore analyic. So, it's an entire function.

Comment: Can you please explain further why f is holmomorphic from ℂ into ℂ. Thanks!

Comment: Because it is differentiable at each point of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Okay I think I see what you mean thanks!